# Run OpenCL without compatible hardware?

Tags: c++, opencl

I have two PCs:

- a new high-end desktop PC, OpenCL compatible CPU and GPU, 32GB RAM
- a very old laptop, Intel Celeron CPU, 512MB RAM, Ati M200 GPU

I am writing an OpenCL/C++ sw on my desktop PC. But when I travel somewhere, I continue the work on my oldschool laptop. Programming C++ on this laptop is good, but I can't try the OpenCL parts of my code. So this time I am writing OpenCL code, but I don't know it is good or not.

Is there a way, to virtualize an OpenCL compatible CPU/GPU? I don't want to get high performance, I just want to try my code, doesn't matter if it is very slow (slower than if I run it 1-thread on my Celeron CPU).

I guess, the answer is no.

(BTW, my plan is, there will be an option in my program, and you can run it with or without OpenCL. This is also needed to measure performance, and compare OpenCL CPU/GPU, and CPU in 1-thread mode without OpenCL.)

almost an answer, but not completely what I am looking for: http://www.acooke.org/cute/Developing0.html

Comment: Have you tried [`ocl-emu`](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-emulator-debugger/)?

Answer (score 2):

For all existing OpenCL implementations, you need some form of SSE.

A website gathering all this info is [here](http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-12-29/opencl-hardware-support/).

The lowest requirements are provided by the AMD OpenCL drivers, which require SSE3. As the list shows, that goes all the way back to late Pentium 4's.

In order to be sure about your CPU's capabilities, you'll need to use something like [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) which can show the capabilities of your processor.

All that aside, I searched for laptops with your GPU, and ended up with processors like the Intel Celeron M 420, which [according to Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/27149/Intel-Celeron-M-Processor-420-1M-Cache-1_60-GHz-533-MHz-FSB?q=%20Intel%20Celeron%20M%20420) doesn't even have 64-bit support (which would imply SSE2).

<s>I currently know of no other OpenCL implementations that are worth anything, so the answer would be **no**.</s>

On the other hand, [some websites claim that processor has SSE3 support](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Celeron_M/Intel-Celeron%20M%20420%20LF80538NE0251M%20%28BX80538420%29.html), so that would mean AMD's OpenCL SDK is your option of choice.

Comment: I think I have Intel Celeron M380, it looks like doesn't support SSE3.

http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Celeron_M/Intel-Celeron%20M%20380%20RJ80536NC0251M%20-%20LE80536NC0251M.html

My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L20-182.

http://www.toshiba.eu/discontinued-products/satellite-l20-182/

So, probably I can't use AMD's API-implementation without SSE3.

Comment: Then you're fresh out of luck for full OpenCL support. Maybe using the ocl-emu stuff @Cicada suggested you might be able to run the code at least

Comment: Maybe ocl-emu is good if you have no compatible hardware, but using Windows and VisualStudio. On my desktop PC there is Windows, but on my laptop I am using LinuxDebian. I will try AMD's implementation on my linux laptop, probably my CPU will not compatible. Worst case I will run the OpenCL code-part in my mind :-D

Comment: Latest Intel OpenCL CPU driver actually requires SSE4.2. A few versions back it only required SSE4.1.